# jQuery, getting a reference error when moving my jquery codes to external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function works when I put it via inline html just before the end of `</body>`. But once I move it to js/main.js it doesn't work anymore.

Inline:

```
<script>
var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
        rowNum ++;
        var html = $('.addphone').html();
        jQuery('.phone_adds').append(html);
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
        jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Versus external .js:

```
$(function() {

.....other functions...

    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
        rowNum ++;
        var html = $('.addphone').html();
        jQuery('.phone_adds').append(html);
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
        jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
    }

});
```

Error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined`

Help? What is wrong here?

Comment: how are you referencing the external js file in your page?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan with `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` before the end of `</body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are enclosing your function into a wrapper:

```
$(function() {

    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
        rowNum ++;
        var html = $('.addphone').html();
        jQuery('.phone_adds').append(html);
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
        jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
    }
});
```

When you do that your defined functions are in fact subfunctions of the wrapper (the "$" function), so, when its called outside from this wrapper, the function doesnt exists.

The "inline" works because your function is global and visible anywhere (is not inside another function).

I would recommend removing the wrapper of the function definition and just leave the function call in the $() wrapper.

Comment: The reasoning is correct; but I'd recommend removing the $(function() { (first line) and the closing }); (last line) to keep things simple.